# When an AW*-algebra is a W*-algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

In a very old book of Kaplansky "Rings of operators", on p. 123 one can find the following sentence:

*It is a standing conjecture that an AW${}^\ast$-algebra is W${}^\ast$ if its center is W${}^\ast$.*

I am wondering what is the current status of this conjecture.

Thank you,
J.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know who solved this problem originally, but see J.D. Maitland Wright, Wild AW∗-factors and Kaplansky-Rickart algebras, *J. London Math. Soc.* 13 (1976), 83–89 for a construction of a family of AW* factors. These have trivial, hence commutative, center.